# How to verify search result in Webdriver/java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Here am having a form contain 10 edit fields with labels and a search box, if i enter the text(Additional Appeal's Information) in the search box the respective field should be displayed in the form..

```
   WebElement createsearch = driver.findElement(By.id("txtSearch"));
```

`createsearch.clear();`

```
createsearch.sendKeys("Additional Appeal's Information");
```

`Boolean assertTrue = driver.findElements(By.id("textfield")).contains("Additional Appeal'sInformation");`

```
 if (assertTrue == true) {System.out.print("Yes"); }else{System.out.print("No");}
```

this is the code i used but, the result shown is always "NO" i just want a help in logic for this,or is there any other way to validate?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `String InsertedString = createsearch.getAttribute("value")` and then compare it with the string `"Additional Appeal's Information"` you inserted

Answer (score 0):

Why in the second query you using different ID? 
- In the first one the ID was "txtSearch", in the second one "textfield".

Also, please notice, in the second one you using `findElements` instead of `findElement`, the last one will return you always one element (in case a couple exist the satisfy the selector - the first one will be returned) while the first one will return a List of them. Verify that the element that you got there is exactly the element you searched for.

And finally, you don't read the text from the element, on the WebElement you have, you should do element.getText() in order to get it's value (String).

Please try this:

```
WebElement myText = driver.findElement(By.id("textfield"));
String text = myText.getText();
println("Text value: " + text); 
if (text.contains("Additional Appeal's Information")){System.out.print("Yes");}else{System.out.print("No");}
```